# Practical definition of stock rating scores

Tags: equities, price, performance-evaluation

I am trying to understand the practical quantitative definitions of the stock scoring system (1-5) that can be commonly found in sell-side analyst predictions. For instance, a score of 3 suggests market average performance, which can be ascertained by following a reasonable index. See image below from Yahoo! Finance:

[image]

Is there a practical quantitative definition used in the industry for scores of 1 vs 2?

For instance, that a score of 2 indicates market outperformance by xx% - yy% while a score of 1 indicates market outperformance > yy%

Comment: I believe these ratings have not been carefully standardized. Which is a bit unfortunate for statistical analysis... The meaning could vary somewhat depending on the person/firm doing the rating and the time period involved. If they do give a definition in a footnote or appendix, it is usually verbal rather than quantitative.

Comment: @noob2 Thanks, I was afraid that was the case. I suppose it more or less limits statistical analysis to binary or tertiary classification only (either outperform/market perform/underperform).